# My OpenGraph is not working to any social media platform like Discord, Twitter and Facebook

Tags: php, html, metadata, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Based on facebook debug here's the error.

[image]

But I don't think That's the problem in SSL Error My SSL is provided by **Let's Encrypt**.
For the other errors meta og is already there for like 48hours now since I last updated my website.

```html
<!--===============================================================================================-->

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        

<!-- HTML Meta Tags -->
<title>Discord Bot | Prunity - Earn real money for free!</title>
<meta name="description" content="Prunity is a optimized mining website application, It allows you to earn money by running the task every 4 hours even you're away from the keyboard.">
<meta name="author" content="Mashwishi">

<!--===============================================================================================-->

<!-- Facebook Meta Tags -->
<meta property="og:url" content="https://prunity.ml">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Discord Bot | Prunity - Earn real money for free!">
<meta property="og:description" content="Prunity is a optimized mining website application, It allows you to earn money by running the task every 4 hours even you're away from the keyboard.">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/UJz86YE.png">

<!--===============================================================================================-->

<!-- Twitter Meta Tags -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:domain" content="">
<meta property="twitter:url" content="https://prunity.ml">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Discord Bot | Prunity - Earn real money for free!">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Prunity is a optimized mining website application, It allows you to earn money by running the task every 4 hours even you're away from the keyboard.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/UJz86YE.png">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Mashwishi" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@Mashwishi" />

<!--===============================================================================================-->
```

I used https://www.opengraph.xyz to generate everything

Comment: Still after a long time, there is no answer to this ;^^) Same problem with me now btw

Comment: April 2022, problem still exists

Comment: I used cloudflare and it work

Comment: Yeah, I have no domain and use noip, that's why it's not working :<